# Problems using BifurcationKit.jl (Julia Language) in a simple ODE

Tags: julia

I am attempting to conduct a bifurcation analysis using BifurcationKit.jl for a simple system of ODEs that describe predator-prey interactions. Specifically, I am interested in observing how changes in the parameter "a" lead to a Hopf bifurcation. For instance, when "a" is set to 0.1, both predator and prey populations stabilize. However, with "a" set to 0.3, the populations exhibit oscillations.

Despite setting up the problem and running the simulation, the resulting bifurcation diagram does not accurately reflect the observed behaviors. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help identify the issue in my code.

Here is the code:

```
using Revise, Parameters, Plots
using BifurcationKit
const BK = BifurcationKit

# vector field of the problem
function COm(u, p)
    @unpack r,K,a,h,eps,mu = p
    x, y = u
    out = similar(u)
    out[1] = r*x*(1.0 - x/K) - a*x*y/(1 + a*h*x)
    out[2] = eps*a*x*y/(1 + a*h*x) - mu*y
    out
end

# parameters used in the model
par_com = (r = 1.0, K = 10.0, a = 0.1, h = 0.5, eps = 0.5, mu = 0.2)

recordCO(x, p) = (x = x[1], y = x[2])

# initial condition
z0 = [0.05, 0.1]

# Bifurcation Problem
prob = BifurcationProblem(COm, z0, par_com, (@lens _.a); record_from_solution = recordCO)
# continuation parameters
opts_br = ContinuationPar(p_min = 0.1, p_max = 1.0, ds = 0.002, dsmax = 0.01)

# compute the branch of solutions
br = continuation(prob, PALC(), opts_br; plot = true, verbosity = 2, normC = norminf)
# plot the branch
scene = plot(br, xlims = (0.1,1.0))
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the results are incorrect?

Comment: Testing out the exact same system in MatCont shows a Hopf point at `a ~ 0.3` and a branch point at `a ~ 0.05`. I'm very curious why BifurcationKit doesn't find the same. I've tried varying quite a few options (forcing `ds` to be very small, switching algorithms, etc.) and I haven't been able to get it to detect any bifurcations.